# Jboss EAP 6.4 Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in Module

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am evaluating to migrate my web application from Jboss7.1 to JBoss EAP 6.4 which has a official support of Java 8.  As part of this, I have installed JBoss EAP 6.4 and jdk1.8.0_45.
My web application is Spring MVC based and hence I have configured all the required spring modules under the JBoss modules folder(<<JBOSS_HOME>>\modules\system\layers\base\org\springframework\main).
With all these configurations done, when I try to deploy my web application, its failing with the below error,

```
16:35:06,197 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in Module "org.springframework:main" from local module loader @9e89d68 (finder: local module finder @3b192d32 (roots: C:\localsetup\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\localsetup\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)): org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.jboss.interceptor:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:78) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1392) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:563) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:285)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]

16:35:06,331 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."web.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."web.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "web.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.jboss.interceptor:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:78) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1392) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:563) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:285)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 5 more
```

Can some one please help me, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have a spring module before when using jboss 7.1? If not, make sure you: dont package it with your war now, and you added a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file with dependency to your spring module

Comment: Yes I had spring module in my jboss 7.1 also.  So I have added those spring modules in Jboss Eap 6.4 and also the dependencies are added in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.  Providing the xml file below for your reference,

Comment: <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
 <deployment>
  <dependencies>
   <module name="org.slf4j" />
   <module name="org.springframework">
    <exports>
     <include path="META-INF**" />
     <include path="org**" />
    </exports>
    <imports>
     <include path="META-INF**" />
     <include path="org**" />
    </imports>
   </module>
   <module name="org.jboss.msc" />
   <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.singleton" />
   <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
  </dependencies>
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Answer (score 0):

For me I've got similar problems. The problem was that the class was available in more than one jar and jboss take it from the wrong JAR.
I could solve it by these steps:

1. Look for the class (I've done it with Eclipse CTRL+SHIFT+T)
2. Than pick the one JAR which is older
3. With `mvn dependency:tree` search from wich dependency the JAR is added to the classpath
4. Step to the dependency from from which it is included and add an exclusion:

   <dependency>
   <!-- the dependency which loads the JAR with the older version of class -->
   <groupId>some.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
   <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
   <groupId>some.other.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>some.other.artifact</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   </dependency>